# Getting Permission Denied to C Drive in GoCD ANt Task. I have installed gocd server on windows 10

Tags: ant, go-cd

I have installed GoCD server on windows10 machine. Created a pipeline which contains ANT job. 
In the second run it is not able to delete content from C drive from windows machine.
Giving error: Permission Denied

Comment: what happens when you open a command prompt with administrator privileges and run the ant task there?

Comment: I tried with RemoveItem of powershell, it worked fine. Thanks